# CSS Three Column Layout - Column Height Problem

Tags: css

I am starting with CSS and have run into the 'equal column height' problem', where floated DIVs have different height depending on their content. I have found several workarounds and attempted to apply [this one](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/equalheight), but havend been successful: in a three column layout all three columns are extended, but the left and the right column seem to overlap with the footer section. (This happens in IE 8 and in FF 3.5.10) Here is the picture:

[image]

I would like all three columns to be of the same size and placed betweed the header and the footer section. Here is the HTML:

```
<body>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="top">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="leftnav">
            <p>Left</p>
        </div>
        <div id="rightnav">
            <p>RightNav</p>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <h4>Footer</h4>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

and here is current the CSS:

```
body
{
    font-family: Verdana, Sans-Serif;
    font-size:0.75em;
    line-height:1.5em;
    margin:1.5em;

}

#container
{
    overflow:hidden;
    min-width: 50em;
    margin: 0.625em auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

#top
{
    padding: 0.5em;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

#top h1
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#leftnav
{
    float: left;
    width: 10em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color:#ec7;
}

#rightnav
{
    float: right;
    width: 10em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color:#db6;
}

#content
{
    margin-left: 10em;
    margin-right: 10em;
    padding-left:3em;
    padding-right:3em;
    padding-top:1em;
    min-width:10em;
    text-align:justify;
    background-color:#bab;
}

#leftnav, #rightnav, #content
{
    padding-bottom:1000em;
    margin-bottom:-1000em;
}

#footer
{
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.5em;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
}
```

As you can see, I am a CSS beginner, and the above is the result of copy/paste and different tweaks I have attempted, so any help is appreciated,

(I have posted this question elsewhere, but without response.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [The Holy Grail](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail)? I've had success with it in the past

Comment: Yes, I have, and it works. I'm just trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Uros, your `top` and `footer` are stuffed in the `container` div. Take them out of the `container` and you'll be closer. (I haven't looked at your CSS, as your HTML isn't following ALA's Holy Grail layout.)

Comment: @sarnold: Thank you for the comment, but the 'workaround' I linked to relies on all three DIVs being in a container DIV with Overflow:hidden.
I realize there are ready-made layouts available out there that I could copy and paste, but this is a learning experience :-). Right now, the thing that bugs me is, with my current layout, why the left and the right columns extend 'in front' of the footer and the middle column extends 'behind' it.

Comment: @sarnold: Sorry for not reading your comment more carefully. Please post it as a new answer so I can mark it an answer.

Comment: @Uros, thanks for the suggestion, but I recommend giving the answer to Darko Z -- without his URL, I'd have never spotted the problem. :)