# Basic 3-column layout in CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm doing an exercise to improve my coding and I'm trying to copy the layout from this page http://imgur.com/pM8owcj

I'm stuck with the 3-column section because each column overlaps the other.

I'm a beginner as you can see, I'll really appreciate any help.

Here is the link with the code: http://codepen.io/porpita/pen/ElKty

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <title>
        Ejercicio Multimedia
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="content">
            <div id="header">
            </div>
            <div id="headermenu">
            </div>
            <div id="imagenprincipal">
            </div>
            <div id="espacio">
            </div>
            <div id="galeria">
                <div id="columna">
                    <div id="movimientos"></div>
                    <div id="eventos"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="exposiciones"></div>
                <div id="noticias"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#content {
width: 1144px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
    height: 140px;
    border: 3px #000 solid;
}

#headermenu {
    height: 40px;
    border: 3px #000 solid;
}

#imagenprincipal {
    height: 429px;
    border: 3px #000 solid;
}

#espacio {
    height: 69px;
    border: 3px #000 solid;
}




#galeria {
    height: 825px;
    border: 3px #000 solid;
}

#columna {
    width: 338px;
    height: 825px;
    border: 3px #000 solid;
    float: left;
}

#movimientos {
    width: 338px;
    height: 353px;
    border: 3px #000 solid;
}

#eventos {
    width: 338px;
    height: 472px;
    border: 3px #000 solid;
}

#exposiciones {
    width: 480px;
    height: 825px;

}

#noticias {
    width: 326px;
    height: 825px;
    border: 3px #000 solid;
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Three Column Layout - Column Height Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222391/css-three-column-layout-column-height-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See the Updated Codepen Here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tmnrj**

The borders you had around the inner elements (`#columna, #exposiciones and #noticias`) were adding to their widths, so 338px wide with a 3px border all around = 344px wide. You either need to reduce the width to compensate for the 6 pixels of border (3px each side) or set `box-sizing: border-box;` on the elements so they include the borders in their widths.

**Reference on Box Sizing: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/**

You were also only floating #columna. You need to float all three (`#columna, #exposiciones and #noticias`) and then set `position: relative; overflow: hidden` on #galeria to make sure it contains them or it will collapse.

**Reference on floats: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/**

On a side note - Adding a background colour to the various elements can help identify what was happening with each as you can see in the above fiddle.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're running into space issues because you are using thick pixel borders. Borders are applied to the *outside* of an element. This means if you set a `width` of `50px`, then add a `border` of `3px` all around, your final width is actually `56px`, or `3px + 50px + 3px`.

MDN has [great documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model) on how the CSS box model works, it'll save you hours of stuffing around.

Rather than trying to manually force things into place, it's often easier to allow the browser to calculate it for you by using percentages instead of fixed values like pixels.

It's also handy to test using `background-color` rather than `border` to identify elements, as the background color won't effect the actual width of your element.

Here's an example of your layout using percentages: **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timmah/cnvppzzo/)**